# Heroku Django value too long for type character varying(20)

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, django-models

The Django website is working fine in development, but on Heroku whenever I create a user instance I get this error

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(20)
```

from Heroku logs the error occurs at:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number).    # It returns an error here 
except User.DoesNotExist:
    user = User.objects.create_user(
                phone_number=phone_number, username=phone_number) # Then another error here
```

my user model looks like this:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ... bunch of other fields that are not related to the question
```

And the method looks like this (Postman):

```
{
    "phone_number": "+200000000000"
}
```

As I said it works perfectly In development, and in pythonanywhere. but for some reason, it gives this weird error on Heroku. I can make a guess that it's because PA and Dev servers were using a Sqlite3 DB while Heroku uses Postgres. Any idea about how to fix this?
Also if using a MySql database will solve the problem are there any docs about how to use it? I'm a newbie to SQL and the only SQL database I worked with was Sqlite3

My settings.py

```
try:
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals()).
    # for some reason when I run python3 manage.py runserver it gives me an error "django_heroku is not defined" So i had to wrap it in a try/catch block to be able to run the server in development. 
    #Please not that I ran it the server in production before without that try/catch block and it worked fine
except:
    pass
```

I don't think this is helpful but It's a RESTFUL API website using djangorestframework and djangorestframework-simplejwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was... Instead of using

```
user.create_user(phone_number=..., username=...)
```

I should use

```
user.create(phone_number=..., username=...)
```

Why? No idea

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make a new instance named username , Because username field is already in django database. So try the following code in your Class User :-

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
```

Comment: This wasn't the answer, but it helped me figure out the answer, thank you so much

Comment: Your very Welcome.

Comment: I know I shouldn't ask here but do you know any good reliable way to send SMS messages to users that doesn't charge per message (like a monthly subscription or so)? It has to be reliable cuz my authentication is as WhatsApp. Again sorry for asking in a wrong place

Comment: you can tell me your email , i will contact you there . Is it good ?